# Save data into array [Swift]

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

```
value:Optional({
"-LMpUBhCddHrShVWPVAx" =     {
    mobile = "(555) 564-8583";
    name = "Kate Bell";
};
"-LMpUBhD9-sX8p2Y3EuB" =     {
    mobile = "(408) 555-5270";
    name = "Daniel Higgins Jr.";
};
"-LMpUBhD9-sX8p2Y3EuC" =     {
    mobile = "888-555-5512";
    name = "John Appleseed";
};
})
```

I have this set of dictionary data which I get from Firebase. But how do I save it into an Array? The data that I want is mobile and name.

Here is my code:

```
func retrieveLists() {

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child("60123456789").child("contact_lists").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print("value:\(value)")

    }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }


    }
```

Comment: so what log do you get in the line print("value:\(value)")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for reference:-

```
if let firebaseDic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    for (_, value) in firebaseDic.enumerated() {
        let mobileNumber = value.value["mobile"]!! as! String                               
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't force unwrap variables this may crash the app

Comment: Yes need to use if let for unwrapping

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
struct Item {
    let mobile:String
    let name:String
}
```

//

```
var content = [Item]()

for k in value.allKeys {

    if let res = value[k] as? [String:String] , let mobile = res["mobile"] , let name = res["name"] {

        content.append(Item(mobile: mobile, name: name))
    }

}
```